# Expandablelistview of multi-level of groups and children

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to make an Expandablelistview of multi-level(more than 3) of  groups and children also.

I used the project here  http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1723152

How  I  can change the class MyExpandableListAdapter to accomplish my task  if the groups and

children in an array manner?

Can someone guides me please ?

```
public String[] groups = { "", "", "", "" };  
public String[][] children = {
{ "", "1", "2", "3" },
{ "", "" }, { "1", "2", "3" },
{ "", "1" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this tutoria](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/), explanations are very clear !

Answer (score 0):

you will have to override the following method in the following manner

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this.children[groupPosition][childPosition];
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.children[groupPosition].length;
}


@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.groups[groupPosition];
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.groups.length;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}
```

Comment: Where will I declare childPosition and what value/s it should take?

Comment: You won't need to define childPosition, it will be called when drawing this child. all you have to pass the list of children and list of groups and handle these methods as defined. Then, handle getChildView and getGroupView to draw both children and groups

Answer (score 0):

```
**parent_view.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/textViewGroupName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSelectHandleLeft="@string/hello_world"
        android:background="#ffffff"

        android:drawableRight="@drawable/downward"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 



**child_view.xml**

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChild"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="#1919A3"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/next" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buy1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
please follow code

public class ExpandableListMainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    // Create ArrayList to hold parent Items and Child Items
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> childimage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ImageView imageView2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create Expandable List and set it's properties
        ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView();
        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);
        // Set the Items of Parent
        setGroupParents();
        // Set The Child Data
        setChildData();
        // Create the Adapter

        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems,
                childItems, childimage);
        adapter.setInflater(
                (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),
                this);
        // Set the Adapter to expandableList
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    }

    // method to add parent Items
    public void setGroupParents() {

        parentItems.add("Chemistry");
        parentItems.add("Mathematics");
        parentItems.add("Physics");
    }

    // method to set child data of each parent
    public void setChildData() {
        // Add Child Items for Fruits
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();

        child.add("Some Basic Concepts");
        child.add("States of Matter");
        child.add("Atomic Structure");
        childItems.add(child);
        childimage.add(R.drawable.check);
        childimage.add(R.drawable.buy2);
        childimage.add(R.drawable.buy1);

        child = new ArrayList<String>();

        child.add("Sets,Relations and Function");
        child.add("Complex Numbers");
        child.add("Quadratic Equations");

        childItems.add(child);
        childimage.add(R.drawable.check);
        childimage.add(R.drawable.check);
        childimage.add(R.drawable.buy1);

        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Physics and Measurement");
        child.add("Kinematics");
        child.add("Laws of Motion");

        childItems.add(child);
        childimage.add(R.drawable.check);
        childimage.add(R.drawable.check);
        childimage.add(R.drawable.buy1);

    }

    public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
        private ArrayList<Integer> childimage;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

        public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents,
                ArrayList<Object> childern, ArrayList<Integer> childimage) {
            this.parentItems = parents;
            this.childtems = childern;
            this.childimage = childimage;
        }

        public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
            this.inflater = inflater;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);
            TextView textView = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
            }
            textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
            String a = child.get(childPosition);

            textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));
            imageView2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            imageView2.setBackgroundResource(childimage.get(childPosition));

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (childPosition == 0 || childPosition == 1) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                ExpandableListMainActivity.this,
                                TestInstactionActivity.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("papername", child.get(childPosition));
                        bundle.putString("testduration", "30 minute");
                        bundle.putString("totalquestion", "25");
                        bundle.putString("testmark", "100");
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please purchase",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);
            }
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems
                    .get(groupPosition));
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return parentItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
            super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
            super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I am working on this code , please I need the xml file for your code, thank you.

Comment: Eclipse also gives error saying :-No enclosing instance of the type ExpandableListMainActivity is accessible in scope at this statement Intent intent = new Intent(ExpandableListMainActivity.this,TestInstactionActivity.class);

Comment: What about TestInstactionActivity class?